# Flask - url_for automatically escapes '=' to '%3D'

Tags: python-3.x, flask

So..  I'm having some issues with Flask's url_for .  The code still works.. but when users navigate to a link that was generated by url_for the link looks bad in the address bar.

Namely, I have a decorated view function as follows:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/page=<int:number")
def index(number=0):
    return "Index Page: {}".format(number)
```

This all works fine except when I try to generate a url for that route.  Calling:

```
url_for("index", number=10)
```

Yields: domain.tld:80/page%3D10

Is there any way to circumvent this issue?  I'd like for '=' to be returned instead of '%3D' when it's built into the route itself.

I only noticed it was doing this when I was testing it in an assert and discovered that the routes were ending up different from what I expected them to be.

At the moment, I have my test case circumvent the issue by using urllib.parse.unquote to fix the url for testing purposes.  I could probably just do that for all urls since I won't have any user input to worry about those causing problems.. but it's there for a reason so.... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you have is to not build the parameter in to the route itself, but use query parameters instead:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    page = request.args.get('page', 0, type=int)
    print(url_for("index", page=10)) # yields /?page=10
    return "Index Page: {}".format(page)

app.run(debug=True)
```

My making use of query parameters for the route, you avoid the issue of Flask encoding the `=` sign in the route definition.

Comment: That could work.. but it would cause the one function to be responsible for many routes as I also have a `@app.route("/post=<int:number>")` defined just below that one...  So for my use case it doesn't actually solve my problem.. rather.. it makes the view logic more complicated.

Comment: Ultimately, I've decided to go with this solution and rewriting my routes.  Mainly, because even though I could use a little lua-esque pattern of reassigning the flask.url_for function and changing it to something that corrects this error... it's a lot of work for a little gain.

Additionally, rewriting my routes allows me a little more flexibility with parameters in the future so I'll go with that.